# ¿Como adjuntar .txt en un email (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, email

Estoy intentando adjuntar en un mensaje un archivo ".txt".
 Cuando ejecuto la aplicación, y en principio es cuando debe mandarse el mensaje, no se llega a enviar nada, no se si es porque no toma bien el archivo o porque razón.
Quiero que el mensaje se envié automáticamente y que el usuario no tenga que interaccionar con la aplicación.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                }
            });

        try {


            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("correoOrigen"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("correoDestino"));
            message.setSubject("asuntoEjemplo");

            MimeBodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
            adjunto.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(new File(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ejemplo.txt"))));

            adjunto.setContent(adjunto,"text/plain");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(adjunto);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.d("MailJob", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

El archivo que quiero enviar se encuentra en la carpeta de descargas del dispositivo, y su nombre es "ejemplo.txt".
Ya he estado mirando en internet varios hilos en los que se habla sobre el mismo tema pero no consigo que me funcione aunque los tome como referencia, yo creo que el problema esta a la hora de coger el archivo, que habré puesto mal la dirección o algo parecido.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio  Jorge1997! realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es **muy importante leer [ask]** que te brinda información de como realizar una pregunta en el sitio, realiza tu pregunta de acuerdo a este documento y obtendrás muy buenas respuestas!, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adjuntar archivos, es necesario que el archivo se encuentre en el disco. Revisando tu código el archivo que deseas enviar se encuentra localizado en ;

```
Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ejemplo.txt";
```

Por lo tanto de esta forma puedes anexar el archivo para enviarlo vía email:

```
        String archivoTXT = "ejemplo.txt";

        //Obtiene la Uri del recurso.
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), archivoTXT ));
        //Crea intent para enviar el email.
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("application/pdf");
        //Agrega email o emails de destinatario.
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@dominio.com" });
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivo .TXT.");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hola te envío un archivo .TXT!"); 
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviar e-mail mediante:"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, con la forma que dices si que se me adjunta el archivo, el problema es que quiero que este se envié de manera automática y que el usuario no tenga que interaccionar con la aplicación.  PD: edito la pregunta para que quede claro este punto.

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe como poder automatizar todo ese proceso?